# Jquery Mobile Login with Yii Issue

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, yii

I'm in serious need of some help!

I have a `YII` application installed with a client side front end framework Jquerymobile (JQM)

I really need some help with this, Basically I need to login via the `loginUserFromClient` function from Yii

The issue is I believe with the way I am asking for the login? When I use Firebug I get the `Get` command, Rather than the examples `Post` Also I get a difference response.

I have only really edited in 2 files which are the cause of this (everying inside yii works fine its just linking htem together)

Here are the two files i have been using (excuse PasteBin)
http://pastebin.com/DN73jtAY
http://pastebin.com/DTZWS1fj

Comment: Please post your code here. In the event the pastebin URLs are no longer available, your post will still be meaningful.

Comment: And do not post the same issue in multiple posts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004176/clientside-yii-login-to-a-clientside-dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post a form, you must explicitly request this.

change

```
 <form id="loginForm">
```

to

```
 <form id="loginForm" method='post'>
```